# Android Volley - Updating cached request after a HTTP POST

Tags: android, caching, networking, android-volley

I have a cached request which returns me a list of items. I create a new item via a HTTP POST which needs to be added to the list. A trivial way to get the new list of items would be to invalidate the cache and re-do the request. But a more optimal way would be to add the item I just created to the already cached request so that I do not have to a network request.

How can I add an item to an existing request cache? If not is there a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to update the cache is not the best idea. In onResponse you should take the response - whatever it is and store it in your data structure. For example some list. and just add there new data received with new http Post.

You can alway access the cache with url of the request.

Comment: if you send a GET request volley automatically caches the data provided you set setShouldCache(true). For POST request the cache does not work, i think, in the same way as in GET.